# Java/Android : passing accelerometer value from onSensorChanged method to onCreateSetContentView()

Tags: java, android

I'm new on Java and Android programming language and this is the first platform that I studied.
I want to ask, how can I access the event.values[1] in this method?

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {synchronized (this){
    if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)

        return;
    mAccVals.x = (float) (event.values[1] * FILTERING_FACTOR + mAccVals.x * (1.0 - FILTERING_FACTOR));
    //mAccVals.y = (float) ((-event.values[1] * FILTERING_FACTOR + mAccVals.y * (1.0 - FILTERING_FACTOR)));
    mAccVals.z = (float) (event.values[2] * FILTERING_FACTOR + mAccVals.z * (1.0 - FILTERING_FACTOR));

    scene.camera().position.x = mAccVals.x * .2f;
    scene.camera().position.z = mAccVals.z * .8f;

    scene.camera().target.x = -scene.camera().position.x;
    scene.camera().target.z = -scene.camera().position.z;

}
```

I want to get event.values[1] and then display it on a textview

```
protected void onCreateSetContentView()
{   
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout_example); 
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.scene1Holder);
        ll.addView(_glSurfaceView);
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splashTitle); 
        myTextView.setText("Test " + event.values[1]  );
        return;                  
 }
```

There's any suggestion how can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you be able to provide some more info regarding your set up and what you want to do. 

Essentially you are looking for something simular to 

`System.out.println(event.values[1]);`

Comment: I want to display the recent value of accelerometer sensor, in this case event.values[1] from onSensorChanged method but I don't know how to pass it to onCreateSetContentView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a field in your `Activity` and assign it to your `R.id.splashTitle`:

```
TextView mTextView;
...
protected void onCreateSetContentView() {
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splashTitle);
    ...
}
```

Then set it's text in `onSensorChanged()` as follows:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    mTextView.setText("Test " + event.values[1]);
    ...
}
```

Or you may store most recent sensor's values in a field:

```
// Class field
float[] mSensorValues;
// In onSensorChanged()
mSensorValues = event.values;
// In onCreateSetContentView()
myTextView.setText("Test " + mSensorValues[1]);
```

To preserve right sequense of `onCreate` and `onSensorChanged` you may use an approach described in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html):

```
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
                                     SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 }

 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
 }
```